# Unable to connect to Network using wicid-curses

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager, i3

**Introduction**

This is a fresh install of Debian stretch + Gnome Using Ethernet cable. Installed the wireless drivers for my Wi-Fi card in my laptop, and then connected to the home network. Decided to Uninstall gnome desktop environment and all of it's packages etc. and installed i3Wm. When booting my laptop and i3, it automatically connects to my home network. However, I want to use wicd-curses for network management, as I'm using i3wm.

**The problem**

When I start up wicd-curses, it says I'm connected. I disconnected from my network and tried to connect again, but this time through wicd. I made sure to have the correct settings such as my interface. I entered my key for the network and saved before connecting. It goes through these stages:

```
Connecting.

Putting interface up

validating authentication…/

not connected
```

I'm not sure how to connect through this Terminal application. The password (key) for the network is correct, and connects automatically on boot. It's when I disconnect through wicd-curses and try to connect through it using this application that it doesn't connect.

***Settings for network and preferences inside wicd-curses:***

```
Saved Preferences:
Wireless Interface: wlp3s0
Wired Interface enp2s0f0

Saved settings:
-use DHCP Hostname
-Use Encryption
-*Entered key*
```

Comment: you may want to have a look at your log files under `/var/log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by purging the application, and then re-installing it. I guess some of the packages were corrupted. After re-installing, it works.